# Advantage Extended Procedure - Create and install

Tags: visual-studio, advantage-database-server

i try to create an AEP for my advantage Database. I create a AEP project on VS2008 and i,ve got the dll. I copy de .dll to the folder where is my datadictionnary. I tried to register my dll with regasm but i've always got the warning to give strong name, but i tried a lot of thing and i got this error again. So i tried to install the AEP but i haven't the ProgId required.

Someone can help me to create and install an AEP?

Thanks

Julien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in the process of building and testing the AEP, you should be able to ignore the warning about the strong name.  Once you are to the stage of deploying the AEP, then it is probably a good idea to give it a [strong name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa720664.aspx).

If you have not seen it, Jensen and Anderson's book has good information about [`creating an AEP`](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/WebHelp/Advantage9.1/mergedProjects/devguide/part1point5/creating_aeps_using_c_with_visual_studio_net.htm).

**Edit** After you have built the AEP, you need to add it to the data dictionary in order to be able to call it.  The data dictionary stores meta data about the procedure (procedure name, parameter information, DLL name, etc.). Then when you call it (e.g., execute procedure myproc('abc', 1, 2, 3);) Advantage can get the information from the dictionary to invoke it. I don't have everything with me right now to go through the steps (Win7 upgrade went awry on my laptop and left me starting over).  But the simplest way to "install" the AEP is to right click on the Stored Procedure node in the dictionary (left pane in Advantage Data Architect). There is an option to create a new procedure.  [This information from the book](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/WebHelp/Advantage9.1/mergedProjects/devguide/part1point5/installing_aeps.htm) might help clarify those steps.

Comment: Hi thanks for the "warning not warning", But my AEP is created, but i don't know how i can use it? So, it's not the creation that cause problem but the using after.

Thanks julien